# Is there a term for an $L^1$-combination of discrete metrics?

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology

Let X be some set and $X^r$ be the space of $r$-tuples of elements of $X$. The discrete metric on $X$ is $d(x,y) = 1$  if $x \neq y$ and $d(x,y) = 0$ if $x=y$. Now, suppose I combine discrete metrics on all of the $r$ dimensions of my tuple, using $L^1$, i.e. $d(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) = \sum_{i=1}^{d} d(x_i,y_i)$, i.e. the distance between two tuples is the number of coordinates on which they differ. This is a metric on $X^r$.

My question: Is there a commonly-used name or term for this metric? I'm sure there must be and it's just on the tip of my tongue.

Note: If $d$ had been the $L^1$ norm (i.e. $d(x,y) = \left|x-y\right|$) then the tuple metric would have been the [Taxicab Metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaxicabMetric.html), a.k.a. the [Manhattan Distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaxicabMetric.html).

Comment: the $1$-product metric https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_metric ? If you meant $\sum_i d(x_i , y_i)$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor: I did, but the 1-product metric is relative to any basic metric. So "the 1-product of discrete metrics"?

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of the "taxicab metric"? I don't think that phrase is used much outside of the contex of the Euclidean plane, but I see no reason that one could not talk about the "taxicab product" of two metric spaces (although in that context there's nothing special about discrete metrics).

Comment: Sure. The wikipedia page defines it for a product of metric spaces $(X_i,d_i)$ for which $d_i$ is already chosen beforehand, so no ambiguity should arise

Comment: @CalvinKhor: I was hoping for more of a "non-compound term", like what LeeMosher suggests. But thanks.

Comment: Fair. Small aside; for a vector valued function $u=u(x) \in ℝ^d$, its $L^p$ norm is usually defined as a $q$-product metric of the components' $p$-norms, but I have never seen it described as such. I therefore suspect there isn't a commonly used name.

Comment: @CalvinKhor: Don't you mean the $p$-product of the $p$-norms?

Comment: Well I've seen $1$-products, and personally prefer to use $1$-products because the algebra is cleaner. When I wrote $q$ I did not intend for it to be in any way related to $p$ like e.g. a Holder conjugate

Answer (score 2):

This is called the $\ell_0$ distance (or $L_0$ distance), e.g., [second page of these notes](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~jeffp/teaching/cs5955/L7-Distances.pdf) or [this blog post](https://rorasa.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/l0-norm-l1-norm-l2-norm-l-infinity-norm/).

The idea is that "the $\ell_0$ norm" of a vector is the size of its support, i.e., the number of nonzero coordinates it has. Accordingly, $\ell_0$ metric is the number of coordinates in which two points differ.

There is a terminological conflict because "$L_0$ norm" is often understood as the limit of "$L^p$ norms" as $p\to 0$, which isn't the same. So one needs to clarify what the term means.

Comment: For finite dimension, why are these not the same?

Comment: Maybe because people want consistent definition for finite and infinite case, and so they make modifications that affect the finite case as well... like weight $2^{-n}$ for $n$th variable.